# Byte Size of other cryptonote network blockchains

Tags: cryptonote, blockchain-size

Is there a resource to see the byte size of other cryptonote network blockchains, such as Monero, Aeon, Boolberry, and more

As many cryptonote networks have the codebase that puts the entire blockchain in memory, I would like to know what kind of resources would be necessary for me to experiment around with them, into the foreseeable future

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try chainradar.com, which may or may not be a trustworthy source.

<strike>But the real answer, and only thing relevant here, is that Monero does not put the entire blockchain into memory, and the rest of the question is therefore mostly beyond the scope of this SE.</strike> The question doesn't apply to Monero but might apply to other cryptonote-based coins that keep the blockchain in memory.

---

Edit: If you used chainradar to get blockchain size, you would probably need to use the API and get the block size for every block in existence and sum them. http://chainradar.com/api

Comment: Where is the byte size of the Blockchain on chainradar

Comment: See my edit. Use the API.

Comment: Ok cool, my question is around computational resources to sync with those networks including monero, not specifically around memory use, but memory would be the most limited resource.... I think it is in scope, there's a ton of non xmr questions here

Comment: Fair enough. Short of just syncing those blockchains, you'll need to do something like what I said in the reply. I'll remove my "out of scope" bit.